# Calculate the mean of the number of balls taken out of the box

Tags: probability

A box contains 10 balls that are numbered $1,\ldots, 10$. We roll a dice and then take out balls one after the other with repetition until the number of the ball that came out is less than or equal to the result of the roll of the cube. Let $N$ be the number of balls taken out of the box. Calculate $E(N)$.

As I understand, the result should be $E(N)=\frac{49}{12}$. But I can't seem to figure it out. Is it possible to explain how did they got this result?

Comment: Can you expand a little bit?  What do you mean by "until the number of balls that come out is less than or equal to the result fo the roll of the cube"?

Comment: @NickPeterson thanks for pointing out the mistake. It should be the number of the ball that came out.

Comment: It encourages people to help when you have explained what you have tried. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @oliverjones Usually I explain what I tried to do but this time I have none. I tried to think in the direction of Wald's' theorem but without any success. I also wanted to go with the definition of the expected value. For that I need to find the probability for each case (zero balls, one ball, two balls, ...) and it's hard.

Comment: Suppose you roll a $1$.  Are you then trying to count the expected number of draws it takes to get the ball numbered $1$?   If so, then just work out the expectation for each possible roll of the die.

Answer (score 1):

This will not be a complete answer but hopefully it helps you get started.

Say we roll the die and get an $i$ where $i \in \{ 1,\dots,6\}$. And let $N :=$ number of balls drawn to get a ball less than or equal to $i$.

Let's analyze some probabilities of $N$:

$P(N=1):$ for this we would need to draw a ball numbered in the range $1, \ldots i$. Now under the assumption we may choose any ball uniformly at random as these sorts of problems are usually assumed to be we get

> $\displaystyle P(N=1) = \frac{i}{10}$ since we have $i$-many balls numbered less than or equal to $i$.

For instance, if $i = 4$ then for $N = 1$ we would need to draw one of the following balls numbered $1,2,3$ or $4$ on the first try. Each has a $\frac{1}{10}$ chance of being drawn and so we sum them up for $\frac{4}{10} = \frac{i}{10}$.

Now let's consider the case $P(N=2)$, this event occurs if we have drawn a number (strictly) greater than $i$ on the first try and then a ball numbered less than or equal to $i$ on the second try. If we have $i$ as our roll then there are $10-i$  many balls (strictly) greater than $i$. Additionally, after we draw this ball there will now be $9$ balls remaining. If we put this together we get:

> $\displaystyle P(N=2) = P(\text{ 1st ball is > $i$ and 2nd ball is } \le i)$

We may continue in this fashion.

We will need to consider what happens as $i$ changes which hints that we should condition on the outcome of our roll of the die.